# Unobtrusively add block in cart

Tags: layout, magento, unobtrusive

For a module I'm working on, I want to add a block in the shopping cart screen, I want to do it unobtrusively and I'd like to place it beneath the cart content and before the other blocks (coupon, shipping estimation, totals, ...).

I've managed to do the *unobtrusive* part: an observer listens to `controller_action_layout_load_before` and if the *FullNameAction* is `checkout_cart_index` it adds a handle of my layout update xml file:
the observer:

```
public function showUpperGifts($observer)
{
    $fullNameAction = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if ($this->_isEnabled &&
        ($fullNameAction == 'checkout_cart_index')) {
            $layoutUpdate = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
                                ->addHandle('my_special_handle');
    }
}
```

and the layout file:

```
<my_special_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="module/block" name="module_block" template="module/block.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</my_special_handle>
```

With this, the content of my phtml file shows up, but I'm not able to place it where I want.
My first try was to use the `before="name.of.block"` attribute, but it doesn't work. If I use `before="whatever"` it goes before everything inside the `checkout.cart` block, and if I use `after="whatever"` it goes after everything. In short it doesn't take the content of `before` or `after` into consideration.
Looking at the XML layout files of Magento's core modules, I realized that those argument for `before` and `after` only appears when the blocks they are placing after or before are inside the right/left columns. So my guess is that it's something special for those columns.

So my question is, can I specify the location of my block inside content? And yes, how?
Another solution would be to load the block asynchronously, as I could then append to the div of my choice the result of the AJAX call, but I'd rather do it in a "normal" way if I can.

Thanks for reading :)