# Custom dropdown attribute on registration form

Tags: php, magento, registration

Follow up to [Adding attributes to customer entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity)

My goal is to make new attribute appear on the registration form. I've added `$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer'));` call which should add the new field. Point is to add new field without modifying register.phtml template directly. I will also need to hook into registration save method to handle ability to select custom answer e.g. 'Other'

Thanks in advance

Comment: problem is that the new attribute doesn't appear on the registration form also it works just fine in backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing is that in the admin all defined customer fields are rendered automatically, but in the frontend they are added in the template (customer/form/register.phtml).
As you don't want to edit the phtml file, you could listen for example to `controller_action_layout_load_before`, check if the *fullActionName* is customer_account_create and then include a layout handle of your module which refers to a template file containing the field you want to add. See for more detailed code my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963878/unobtrusively-add-block-in-cart).

Then you'll need another observer listening to Mage_Customer_AccountController's createPostAction method to process the field's value.
Hope That Helps

Comment: I see, so there seems no use for `customer_account_create` in this case at all? However considering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549112/can-no-longer-add-registration-fields-in-magento-1-4-2-0/4617655#4617655 it probably helps loading the attribute value